# why I get “System.Data.DataRowView” in my LookUpEdit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I wanna ask about datatable. I run my code and try to select a 'position' all I get back in my LookUpEdit is System.Data.DataRowView.

help me, pls

code :

```
  using (clsConnection oConn = new clsConnection())
    {
        string vpositionid = @"select positiondesc from tbm_position where dlt='0'";
        positionid.Properties.DataSource = oConn.GetData(vpositionid);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Ok,may be you can parse DataTable to List

```
class MyType{
   public int Positiondesc { get; set; }
}


List<MyType> listName = dataTableName.AsEnumerable().Select(m => new 
MyType()
{
   Positiondesc = m.Field<int>("positiondesc")
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add databind method after assigning the datasource?
also make sure to add

```
positionid.DataSource = objDataTable;
positionid.DataTextField = "Name";
positionid.DataValueField = "Id";
positionid.DataBind();
```

I hope this will helps.